# How do I achieve this curry function "add" with square bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, currying, es6-proxy

My friend sent this picture to me, shows the function `add` that can chain numbers indefinitely, then output the sum.

[image: screenshot]

I was thinking of using `Proxy` to add key numbers together and rewrite its `Symbol.toPrimitive` function, but it seems it doesn't work and I'm not sure what is going on...

Am I on the right direction or is there a better way to do it?

```js
let add = new Proxy(
  {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
      return this.value;
    },
    value: 0
  },
  {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
      if(Symbol.toPrimitive === key) {
        return target[Symbol.toPrimitive];
      } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
        target.value += +key;
      }
      return add;
    },
  }
);

console.log(+add[1]);
console.log(+add[1][2][3]);
console.log(+add[10][-5][3][100]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` inside of your `[Symbol.toPrimitive](){}` method is your proxy, and not your `target` object (ie: your first object argument to the proxy constructor). This causes your proxy get trap to trigger, which results in your `toPrimitive` method not returning a primitive, but instead an object (and so your code throws). This is because, when you perform:

```js
console.log(+add[1]);
```

you are converting the Proxy (`add[1]`) to a primitive number value. When this occurs, JavaScript will try and grab the `Symbol.toPrimitive` function from that proxy. When that occurs, your `get` trap in your handler object runs, and returns the `Symbol.toPrimitive` function object defined on your target object. The engine then invokes this returned function with the `this` value *set to the proxy* (**not** the handler object). In code, you can think of the following occurring when JS converts your proxy, `add[1]`, to a number:

```js
const input = add[1]; // your proxy
const exoticToPrim = input[Symbol.toPrimitive]; // gets the Symbol.toPrimitive function from your object
const result = exoticToPrim.call(input, "number"); // !! calls `Symbol.toPrimitive` !!
```

The above steps are outlined in the spec [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-toprimitive). As you can see from the last line, your `Symbol.toPrimitive()` function is invoked with `this` set as your proxy value, which results in the following code also causing your get trap to fire:

```js
[Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
  return this.value;
}
```

above, `this.value` triggers your `get` method in your handler object to fire with a key of `value`, as `this` represents your proxy, causing the get trap to trigger. Because your get trap returns a proxy when `key` is set to `value`, your `Symbol.toPrimitive` method doesn't return a primitive, but rather it returns your `app` proxy, which causes your code to throw. A simple quick fix is to handle the case when `value` is accessed on your object (note that I've also reset `value` so that each log doesn't accumulate from the previous):

```js
let add = new Proxy(
  {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
      return this.value;
    },
    value: 0
  },
  {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
      if(key === Symbol.toPrimitive) {        
        return target[key];
      } else if(key === 'value') {
        const sum = target[key];
        target[key] = 0;
        return sum;
      } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
        target.value += +key;
      }
      return add;
    },
  }
);

console.log(+add[1]);
console.log(+add[1][2][3]);
console.log(+add[10][-5][3][100]);
```

Another option is to change the `toPrimitive` function that gets invoked, which you can do by returning a function that wraps your `toPrimitive` function and invokes it with a new `this` value that is set to the `target` object. You can also reset your value count in this new wrapper function:

```js
let add = new Proxy(
  {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
      return this.value;
    },
    value: 0
  },
  {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
      if(key === Symbol.toPrimitive) {        
        return (...args) => {
          const prim = target[key].apply(target, args);
          target.value = 0;
          return prim;
        };
      } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
        target.value += +key;
      }
      return add;
    },
  }
);

console.log(+add[1]);
console.log(+add[1][2][3]);
console.log(+add[10][-5][3][100]);
```

Comment: Wow! Now I get it. Great detail for clearing the `value` after accessing it. Thank you so much for the elaborated explanation!